# How can I resolve in AXS with metamask, to bridge ETHMainnet to zkevm, this don't work

Tags: ethereum, metamask, bridge, mining

in https://erc20.mxc.com/
I try to bridge ETHMainnet to zkvem for be able to pay the Gas...[I had 1236 MXC, (ERC20)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRWX7.png)
I read https://mxc-foundation.gitbook.io/mxc-gitbook/axs-migration-guide/table-of-contents/using-mxc-zkevm-obtaining-zkevm-mxc-for-gas-via-bridge,

This don't work...
Can somebody help me ?

I tried to change the network to Ethereum Mainnet and I tried to MXC zkEVM Mainnet, receiving don't work, in MetaMask on Dashboard I have the MXC ready...
[In metamask Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCRiv.png)
Can somebody Help to understand what's wrong with this ?